# SQL - Sum and Case function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum, case

I need to get the sum of a column that is called prodflag that is only 1 and 0. However the tricky part is that I need to get the sum work in buckets of 4 weeks so something like this:

1. first bucket: week 14,13,12,11
2. second bucket: week 10,9,8,7
3. third bucket: week 6,5,4,3

```
select
      person
    , sup
    , program
    , city
    , sum( case when weekraw between DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -3, GETDATE()))  and  DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) then prodflag else 0 end) firstbucket
    , sum( case when weekraw between DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GETDATE()))  and  DATEPART(WEEK,-3, GETDATE()) then prodflag else 0 end) secondbucket
    , sum( case when weekraw between DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -9, GETDATE()))  and  DATEPART(WEEK,-6, GETDATE()) then prodflag else 0 end) thirdbucket    
from final
group by 
      person
    , sup
    , program
    , city
```

However I think that the sum combined with the case won't work as when I try to get this part of the code to work it gives me an error:

```
, sum(
        case when weekraw between DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GETDATE()))  and  DATEPART(WEEK,-3, GETDATE()) then prodflag else 0 end) secondbucket
```

I'm missing something or in this case what the best way to go?

Comment: Sorry the tag is wrong, I will remove it

Comment: What is the error?  What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the query throws an error, could be the case that the field 
`weekraw` is not of type number or contains `null` values. If you mean that it gives you a value that you did not expected, this could be because of the values in the substraction:

```
, sum( case when weekraw between DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -3, GETDATE()))  and  DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) then prodflag else 0 end) firstbucket
, sum( case when weekraw between DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -7, GETDATE()))  and  DATEPART(WEEK,-4, GETDATE()) then prodflag else 0 end) secondbucket
, sum( case when weekraw between DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -11, GETDATE()))  and  DATEPART(WEEK,-8, GETDATE()) then prodflag else 0 end) thirdbucket
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is Weekraw is already a numeral, as you are comparing against weeknumbers.

You can simply go for CASE logic with IN condition.

```sql
select
      person
    , sup
    , program
    , city
    , sum( case when weekraw in (11,12,13,14) then prodflag else 0 end) AS firstbucket
    , sum( case when weekraw in (10,9,8,7) then prodflag else 0 end) AS secondbucket
    , sum( case when weekraw in (6,5,4,3) then prodflag else 0 end) AS thirdbucket
from final
group by 
      person
    , sup
    , program
    , city
```